# Order by distinct result throws an error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to run the following pseudo query in the browser:

```
Match (p:Person)...
return distinct {personID: p.personID...}
order by p.PersonID
```

throws the following error:

> p is not defined.

If I remove "distinct" then it works fine. Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've created the custom object in the `RETURN` statement **and** removed duplicates using `DISTINCT`, `p.personId` doesn't exist anymore, so you can't use it to order the results.

You need to introduce a step creating the distinct tuples with all the elements of the custom object, which you can order, before creating the custom object itself:

```
MATCH (p:Person)...
WITH DISTINCT p.personId AS personId, p.otherProp AS otherProp...
ORDER BY personId
RETURN {personId: personId, otherProp: otherProp...}
```

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks a lot!